# Asterisk AMI events for incoming call with caller id

Tags: node.js, asterisk

I want to put listener for incoming and outgoing calls, and I am using **[AMI Events](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+AMI+Events)**

I've successfully managed to put the listener for outgoing calls via event `DialBegin`

But I am not able to find an event for an incoming call,

I've somehow manage to find another event for the incoming call but, in that case I am not getting `callerId`.

So want to find some proper solution for this, if this is possible with AMI and if not then what else.

Comment: I use NewConnectedLine

Answer (score 1):

You have check NewChannel events and track actions after that.

There are no simple ways detect something like that. At least no way describe it in one screen.

Comment: I've also tried that and tracked the `NewChannel` events, but how to identify that channel is created for incoming call or outgoing calls then.`track actions` will you please explain bit more about this , and there is any need of AGI or we can achieve this only with AMI?

Comment: Track all events and read it. Yes, it is doable via AMI, but VERY not trivial, not homework project.

Comment: You can check FOP(flash operator panel) project to get more ideas what to track. Note, channel can be renamed and re-bridged on transfer etc.